# Optimize pandas loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this loop in order to calculate a value for same datetimes in a dataframe

```
   for epoch in data_all['EPOCH'].unique():
    data_epoch = data_all.query('EPOCH==@epoch')
    data_epoch['SIGMA'] = pd.to_numeric(data_epoch['SIGMA'].values)
    variance = np.mean(data_epoch['SIGMA'].values ** 2)
```

But that is very slow. Could you one way to do that faster?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just groupby:

```
variances = data_all.groupby('EPOCH')['SIGMA'].var()
```

Or if you want to use your formular:

```
variances = (data_all['SIGMA']**2).groupby(data_all['EPOCH']).mean()
```

---

**Update** For your add-on question:

```
variances = data_all.groupby('EPOCH')['SIGMA'].transform('var')
data_all['GROUP'] = (variances<1).astype(int)
```

Comment: And if Do I want create other column depending on the variance value? For example:
if variances < 1, in this epochs the value in new column 'GROUP' will be 1, if not 0. How I evaluate that in each epoch without a loop? Thank you

Comment: Sorry for doing other question. I should make better my ask. I would say can separate the GROUP value in three possibles values, not only one. For example in [1, 2, 3] depending if If var > 0.08 group 1, if var > 0.008 group 2, if var > -0.1 group 3. Thanks very much!

Comment: @jatorna use `np.select` or `pd.cut` on the `variances` generated by `transform` in the update.